# Как преобразовать список в массив чисел на Python

Tags: python, imap

```
    typ, data = mail.search(None, '(FROM "моя_почта")')

    # Вывод всех значений

    mb.showinfo("Окно", data)
```

Проблема в том, что этот код выдает мне очень большой список list [image: Тот самый список] Мне этот List нужно преобразовать в массив. Для того, что бы я потом мог взять от туда случайное число. Но не могу понять как это сделать, постоянно выдает ошибки разные.

Comment: А что вам мешает взять случайное число из list? Генерируйте случайный индекс в диапазоне индексов списка и получаете. У вас уже по сути массив и есть

Comment: np.array? <!-- -->

Comment: А вы можете показать как это будет выглядеть в коде? Не судите строго, я с таким еще не сталкивался))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в левом верхнем углу есть `{`, значит это `set`. поэтому просто напишите `data = list(data)`

---

вывод рандомных значений

```
import random

typ, data = mail.search(None, '(FROM "моя_почта")')
data = list(data) 

mb.showinfo("Окно", random.choice(data))
```

Comment: mb.showinfo("Окно", data.random()) когда я пытаюсь вывести рандомное число прежде сделав, то , что вы сказали, он выдает ошибку ( AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'random' )

Comment: @Karlson12 у меня все работает

Comment: Все, да пофиксил, спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint

my_list = []
#Создаю такой же список как и у тебя
for i in range(1,1001):
    my_list.append(i)
    if i == 1000:
        break
#Тут рандомно генерирую индекс по которому буду 
выбирать число из списка
random_number = randint(0,1001)
      #список  #рандомный индекс
print(my_list[random_number])
```

Вроде бы все понятно обьяснил